# I would like to know how to display only one specific element of the collection instead of the whole collection

Tags: mongodb, meteor, reactjs

I'm working  with meteor react and mongo collections.

```
class App extends Component {
    renderVraag() {
        return this.props.vragen.map((vraag) => (
            <Vraag key={vraag._id} vraag={vraag} />
        ));
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <header>
                    <h1>vragen</h1>
                </header>

                <ul>
                    {this.renderVraag()}
                </ul>
                <button className="yes">
                    yes
                </button>
                <button className="no">
                    no
                </button>
            </div>
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Can you show us what `this.renderVraag()` looks like? What does it return? Elements? Data Array?

Comment: It is there. Just above the `render()` method.

Comment: What if you try to render it like this: `<ul>{this.renderVraag()[0]}</ul>`?

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to `.filter()` before you `.map()`, like:

```
renderVraag() {
  return this.props.vragen
  .filter(vraag => {
    // some logic that returns true for any item you want to include like:
    return vraag._id === 123;
  })
  .map(vraag => {
    return <Vraag key={vraag._id} vraag={vraag} />;
  });
}
```

More about `.filter()` in [the MDN docs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter).